# Youtube short related video from youtube API

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When creating a mix on YouTube, it's link automatically his original video.

Even when uploading manually from YouTube Studio, there is the possibility to link the short to its original video. How can this be achieved through the API?

Here is the screenshot from youtube studio:

[image: youtube studio]

Comment: did you found the answer for this?

Comment: @AriyanSharif unfortunately no..